# if duplicate entry found then add 1 in the count of previous specfic column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
i have a dataframe like this in pandas 

              StartTime     EndTime             RuleCount   duser    pastcount   pastfire

 1       2020-09-04 17:19:30 2020-09-04 17:20:00      9         test        1          10
 2       2020-09-04 17:21:30 2020-09-04 17:22:00      9         test1       2          20
 3       2020-09-04 17:22:30 2020-09-04 17:23:00      9         test        1           5
 4       2020-09-04 17:15:30 2020-09-04 17:16:00      9         test        1           5
 5       2020-09-04 17:17:30 2020-09-04 17:18:00      9         test1       1           5
 6       2020-09-04 17:19:30 2020-09-04 17:20:00      9         test3       0           5
```

i want output like below. if duser is found for the first time then simply copy the pastcount in repeat column if it exist one more time then add the previous value of repeat column by plus 1 and so on.

```
              StartTime     EndTime       RuleCount     duser    pastcount   pastfire   repeat

 1       2020-09-04 17:19:30 2020-09-04 17:20:00      9         test        1          10  1
 2       2020-09-04 17:21:30 2020-09-04 17:22:00      9         test1       2          20  2
 3       2020-09-04 17:22:30 2020-09-04 17:23:00      9         test        1           5  2
 4       2020-09-04 17:15:30 2020-09-04 17:16:00      9         test        1           5  3
 5       2020-09-04 17:17:30 2020-09-04 17:18:00      9         test1       1           5  3
 6       2020-09-04 17:19:30 2020-09-04 17:20:00      9         test3       0           5  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.transform` with `cumcount`:

```
g = df.groupby("duser")
df["repeat"] = g["pastcount"].transform("first") + g["duser"].cumcount()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
             StartTime              EndTime  RuleCount  duser  pastcount  \
1  2020-09-04 17:19:30  2020-09-04 17:20:00          9   test          1   
2  2020-09-04 17:21:30  2020-09-04 17:22:00          9  test1          2   
3  2020-09-04 17:22:30  2020-09-04 17:23:00          9   test          1   
4  2020-09-04 17:15:30  2020-09-04 17:16:00          9   test          1   
5  2020-09-04 17:17:30  2020-09-04 17:18:00          9  test1          1   
6  2020-09-04 17:19:30  2020-09-04 17:20:00          9  test3          0   

   pastfire  repeat  
1        10       1  
2        20       2  
3         5       2  
4         5       3  
5         5       3  
6         5       0
```

Comment: is it possible to pass mutiple column like currently we have passed duser suppose i want duser along with src
is it possible??

Comment: Then the code may have to be modified slightly. But i don't see `src` in your sample data :(